# Python Selenium: Remove certain characters from web page body

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, dom

I'm running Selenium with Firefox in Python, and I'm trying to match Elements on a page from keywords in a list.

For the element lookup to be successful, I need to get rid of some special characters like ® and ™ on the web page. I am unfortunately not able to predict when such characters are employed, and I therefore can't add them on the "keyword end" of the problem.

I don't think that Selenium or Firefox itself can remove unwanted characters from a webpage, but my thought was to have Selenium execute a JavaScript on the page and remove those characters. Is that possible?

Something like this presumably non-working, pseudo-code:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.innerHTML.replace(/&reg;/g, '');")
```

The replacement should happen before the driver tries to "read" the page and `find_element`.

FYI the characters I want to get rid of are in `<a>` `text()` nodes in `<td>` cells across the document body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is in range of 0 to 127, so you can do it this way:

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, '');
```

If you want to remove only ® you can do it this way:

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(®)/, '');
```

Comment: This worked for me: `driver.execute_script("var replaced = $('body').html().replace(/(®)/g,''); $('body').html(replaced);")`, from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550100/4909923) with your help.

Comment: I think it is much shorter and easier to read way:
`driver.execute_script("document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(®)/, '');")`

Comment: I agree with you there. But when running that command in the Chrome Javascript console, it didn't re-render the page (although I could see HTML output in the response console). Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Please try this code, i am sure it works:
`page_source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(®)/‌​, '');")`
Now "page_source" contains re-rendered page source.